# CSCI Major with a love for film

Tags: self-learning

I am about to start my second semester of community college with the intention of transferring to a state university, where I will pursue a degree in computer science. I think this is a good fit for me, as I love logic, coding, math, and am doing well at a software development internship. Problem solving is one of my best strengths, so I don't foresee any issues with my studies.

This being said, I love cinematography, visual effects, and story telling itself. I appreciate the art of cinema for both its technical and creative aspects and would love to be involved in this industry too.

Can I realistically combine both of these passions into one career? If so, how?

Comment: Hello, Mr.Technician, and welcome to [cseducators.se]!  Unfortunately, you've come to the wrong forum.  This is essentially a focused forum for educators to do Q&A about teaching strategies within the CS sphere.  That said, I've combined music and CS, so I don't see any reason why film and CS couldn't be combined.  CS is in every field nowadays, so for that sort of targeted advice, I might go to film industry forums and ask around there.  Ask about what people do, and ask about how to position yourself to hit the ground running in those fields.  You're on the right track.  Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to [cseducators.se], a site designed to help people teach Computer Science, including many of the problems they might face when doing so. Self-learning can be seen as _teaching_, with yourself as the student. How to apply CS learning to different fields of work, however, is a bit beyond the scope of the site. That being said, computers, and those who can program them are just about everywhere, so using your CS education in cinematography ought to be simple enough. The "How" as they say, _is left as an exercise for the reader_.

Comment: Off topic, but: Yes. You sound like the type of person that I would love to teach. Both computer gaming, TV, and movies use both use these skills. In addition story telling will be of help in computer science.

Comment: Thanks! My apologies for being off topic, I will take this question elsewhere. :)

@ctrl-alt-delor That's good to hear. I guess I'm just trying to find my niche and keep that in mind as I go through college.

Comment: An outstanding cinematographer cum computer scientist could revolutionize our field. For a scratch-the-surface beginning see my answer on [youtube vs books](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/6182/8837). Of course this is not remotely a subject that you chould study as a student yet but cutting edge research... if you want to be the researcher!